# What is a good practice for a calculated field when using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Imagine I have a model with a first_name and a last_name. If I want the calculated attribute "full name", I see 2 solutions:

**1) an accessor in the model**

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

**2) use a resource**

For example :

```
class UserResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'full_name' => "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}"
        ....
```

Are there other solutions? I am a little confused about the good choice. What are the pros and cons of these 2 solutions? What are you using on your side ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also create your own function

```
public function getFullName()
{ 
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

The array function is mostly used when you are creating an API (not a rule)

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'full_name' => "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}"
    ....
```

And the most common solution is to use a getter:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

So the conclusion is.... there is no "the best solution" all of them work just fine, programmers make different ways to get the data.